# Bringing a list of CD-DA timings into an emacs calc vector

Tags: emacs

I would like to split an autogenerated CUE sheet containing many songs into groups with total lengths under 74 or possibly 80 minutes for burning to CDs.  The list of song durations appears in the CUE sheet in the following format:

```
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 03:55:72
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 02:18:59
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 04:21:43
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 02:15:26
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 04:56:72
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 03:37:30
REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE 05:02:73
...
```

These are in the format MM:SS:FF - minutes, seconds, and Compact Disc Digital Audio (CD-DA) frames, with 75 CD-DA frames to the second.  I would like to grab a rectangle of some of these timings into a Calc vector in Emacs using `M-x calc-grab-rectangle`, and then sum them to produce a final MM:SS:FF number (where MM < 99).  Would this require creating a new 'type' in emacs Calc, or an automatic conversion to one of the built-in types?  Is there related code for Calc to handle this sort of format parsing and type conversion?

Or minimally, I'd like to be able to grab some MM:SS numbers as a rectangle, and have it automatically convert them to a vector of emacs Calc 'HMS forms', so I can just sum the minutes and seconds using the built-in functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lisp code collects the cue time strings in the current buffer starting at point and puts them onto the `calc` stack:

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'calc)

(defun cue-collect-times ()
  "Collect times in cue-format starting at point and put them in hms format on the calc stack."
  (save-excursion
    (calc-push-list 
     (loop while (re-search-forward "^REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE \\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):" nil t)
       collect (list 'hms 0 (string-to-number (match-string 1)) (string-to-number (match-string 2)))))))
```

I did neglect the frames. Hope this is okay.

You can also put the times as vector on the stack:

```
(defun cue-collect-times-as-vector ()
  "Collect times in cue-format starting at point into a calc vector and put it on the stack."
  (save-excursion
    (calc-push-list (list (append '(vec)
     (loop while (re-search-forward "^REM FILE-DECODED-SIZE \\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):" nil t)
       collect (list 'hms 0 (string-to-number (match-string 1)) (string-to-number (match-string 2)))))))))
```

Comment: Well, that was quick.  Very much appreciated.